# WPF Templates error - "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception."

Tags: wpf, templates, visual-studio-2010, binding

I've just started experimenting with WPF templates vs. styles and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The goal below is to alternate the colors of the options in the menu.  The code works fine with just the , but when I copy and paste/rename it for the second segment of "MenuChoiceOdd" I get the following error:

*> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.*

Sample of the code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Template_Testing"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Template_Testing" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuChoiceEven">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF4A5D80">
                <TextBlock Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"  Width="Auto" FontSize="14" Foreground="SlateGray" TextAlignment="Left" AllowDrop="True" Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <TextBlock.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC2CCDB" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </TextBlock.Background>
                </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuChoiceOdd">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF4A5D80">
                    <TextBlock Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"  Width="Auto" FontSize="14" Foreground="SlateGray" TextAlignment="Left" AllowDrop="True" Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <TextBlock.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="##FFCBCBCB" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </TextBlock.Background>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>            
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Border BorderBrush="SlateGray" BorderThickness="2" Margin="10" CornerRadius="10" Background="LightSteelBlue" Width="200">
            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                <TextBlock Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,2,2,0" Name="MenuHeaderTextBlock" Text="TextBlock" Width="Auto" FontSize="16" Foreground="PaleGoldenrod" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="10" FontWeight="Bold"><TextBlock.Background><LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0"><GradientStop Color="LightSlateGray" Offset="0" /><GradientStop Color="DarkSlateGray" Offset="1" /></LinearGradientBrush></TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,0,2,0" Name="MenuChoicesStackPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
                    <Button Template="{StaticResource MenuChoiceEven}" Content="Test Even menu element" />
                    <Button Template="{StaticResource MenuChoiceOdd}"  Content="Test odd menu element" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It'd be handy if the exception included a line number...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oy it's Monday...

When I copied pasted the color string from another control it put two "##"s in the prefix here:

```
<GradientStop Color="##FFCBCBCB" Offset="1" />
```

Still a lousy error message.

Comment: Newbie in WPF here, and it really is a scary error message

Answer (score 6):

Similarly to others - this horrific error message just meant I had a syntax error in my xaml:

```
<CheckBox Height="" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="80">
```

Notice I hadn't filled in the height value..

Comment: Mine was similar, but because I did Button Command="CommandName" instead of Command="{Binding Path=CommandName}".

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error caused by:

```
<Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="" Width="Auto"/>
```

fixed by putting a number in BorderThickness

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I changed the project name. After I got this error. I re-selected the images and saw that I needed to change the resource name of images too.

```
        <Image x:Name="imgSrc" Grid.Row="1" Source="/PREV%20-%20Filter;component/Images/Subtraktive%20Farbmischung%20%28Malen%20mit%20Wasserfarben%29.jpg" />
```

/PREV%20-%20Filter;component needs to be corrected to /DSP%20-%20Filter;component in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning Width="*" on Grid gave me the error, which looks weird at the first time, but all it is trying to say is that the markup couldn't be converted to actual type.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike others, I had my XAML syntax correct.

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\previous_icon.png" />
```

This error started appearing when i changed my image - later realised i did change the image in my folder but forgot to **Include** it in my project .

Hence although XAML could show me the image in 'Desgn' View - I faced this exception @ run time.
*Silly one.*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when using Grey instead of Gray in my BorderBrush

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Grey"/>
```

instead of

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another instance of this error and how I resolved it.

This appears to have been caused by upgrading my project from VS2010 to VS2012 and VS2013. Not sure exactly why that would be an issue here, but I guess it is.

I developed a Visual Studio Wizard to automate the process of adding a project to our very large solution (300+ projects) as there are additional requirements for us developers to help maintain the project. I used WPF for the wizard and that worked well for VS2010. I upgraded the project to VS2012 and VS2013 and I started getting this error. Turns out that at some point the path to my icon and image files was screwed up. Once I corrected it - which I did directly within the XAML - I stopped getting the error.

In case you may need help referencing resources - this is the post I used to correct my issues: [How to reference an icon resource file reference in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158561/how-to-reference-an-icon-resource-file-reference-in-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same when I forgot curly brackets:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsWhiteboardShared}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="StaticResource AccentColorBlueBrush"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was tasked to fix a bug where a similar error message was being shown ad infinitum. When I found out that the following caused the issue, I was a little disappointed (Was expecting something more complex and catastrophic!):

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource LinkButton}" TargetType="Button" >
```

where **LinkButton** should have been **LinkButtonStyle**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but was using the wrong path for an image in the resources folder

I had this...

```
<controls:ImageButton Grid.Column="2" ImageButtonSource="Resources/close_normal.png"/>
```

but i needed this...

```
<controls:ImageButton Grid.Column="2" ImageButtonSource="../Resources/close_normal.png"/>
```

Had to add ../ at the start to go back one folder first

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using 'OutBox' for this code:

```
                      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="OutBox" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

OutBox was Unknow Value so changed to 'StopCircle' then fixed...

Answer (score 0):

This exact context of the exception seems to vary as others answers point out but generally it occurs when value in beetwen "" in XAML has some incorrect data in it.

I encounteted the error in the same circumstances as [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4359306/james) and it helped me to look at what's inside of InnerException which contained the actual exception cause.